# Hibernate saveOrUpdate() tries to save when it should update

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Hibernate entity called IssueParticipant. It basically describes the relationship between a user and an issue (which is like a JIRA or Bugzilla issue). It represents a sort of many-to-many linking table in the database, linking a user ID to an issue ID, but also includes other information related to notification settings, and so it is treated as its own entity.

I was having huge problems with using the userId and issueId as a composite key, so I created a synthethic key which is a String (and a varchar in the postgres database), which is formed as: _.

Now, I have a screen where a user can edit all of the users associated with an issue, while also editing the notification settings. In a controller class I create a List of IssueParticipants like this:

```
IssueParticipant participant = new IssueParticipant();
participant.setUser(accountUser);
participant.setIssue(issue);
```

So these are of course not managed by Hibernate at this point.

Then in my DAO I iterate through them and call saveOrUpdate(), expecting that if an IssueParticipant with the same synthetic key exists in the database, it will updated; otherwise it will be inserted:

```
    for (IssueParticipant participant : participants) {
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(participant);
        savedIds.add(participant.getIssueUserKey());
    }
```

(savedIds is a List I am maintaining so that I later will know what IssueParticipants I should delete from the database).

Instead of what I expect, though, I get an Exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "issue_participant_pkey"
```

Here is my entity class, abbreviated:

```
public class IssueParticipant extends Entity {

    private String issueUserKey;
    private Long issueId;
    private Long userId;

     // Edit: adding 'dateAdded' definition
    private Date dateAdded;
// ...

    // below may be null
    private SPUser user;
    private Issue issue;

    public static IssueParticipant nulledIssueParticipant() {
        IssueParticipant ip = new IssueParticipant();
        return ip;
    }
    public String getIssueUserKey() {
        return issueUserKey;
    }

    public void setIssueUserKey(String issueUserKey) {
        this.issueUserKey = issueUserKey;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        // currently meaningless
        return 0L;
    }

    public Long getIssueId() {
        return this.issueId;
    }

    public void setIssueId(Long issueId) {
        this.issueId = issueId;
        updateKey();
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        updateKey();
    }

    private void updateKey() {
        issueUserKey = getIssueId() + KEY_SEP + getUserId();
    }

    public SPUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(SPUser user) {
        this.user = user;
        setUserId(user.getId());
    }

    public Issue getIssue() {
        return issue;
    }

    public void setIssue(Issue issue) {
        this.issue = issue;
        setIssueId(issue.getId());
    }

// edit: adding 'dateAdded' methods
public Date getDateAdded() {
    return dateAdded;
}

public void setDateAdded(Date dateAdded) {
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
}

...

}
```

Here is its hbm file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
    <class name="com.xxx.yyy.IssueParticipant" table="issue_participant">
        <id name="issueUserKey" column="issue_user_key" type="string">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id> 
        <version name="dateAdded" column="date_added" type="timestamp" unsaved-value="null" />
        <property name="issueId" column="issue_id" />
        <many-to-one name="user" column="user_id" class="com.xxx.yyy.SPUser" not-null="true" cascade="none" />
        <property name="alertRss" column="alert_rss" type="boolean" />
        <property name="alertEmail" column="alert_email" type="boolean" />
        <property name="alertWeb" column="alert_web" type="boolean" />
        <property name="alertClient" column="alert_client" type="boolean" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And indeed `user_issue_key` is the primary key in the corresponding database table.

I feel like the right solution might just be to use `SpringJDBC` in this case, but I'd really love to figure out what's going on here. Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`saveOrUpdate()` doesn't query the database to decide whether it should save or update the given entity. It makes that decision based on the state of the entity, as follows:

> - if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
> - if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
> - if the object has no identifier property, save() it
> - if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
> - if the object is versioned by a  <version> or  <timestamp>, and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
> - otherwise update() the object

So, as far as I understand in your case decision is based on the value of `dateAdded` field, therefore you need to keep it to distinguish between new and detached instances.

**See also:**

- [11.7. Automatic state detection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-saveorupdate)

Comment: Once upon a time I must've known this, since I created the HBM file (must be close to two years ago at this point). At any rate, your pointing out the unsaved-value role within dateAdded is what I needed; thanks! Once I get more reputation points, or I can find my previous login credentials, I'll thumbs-up your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it to query the database to make this determination if you really want to.  Change your identifier mapping to:

```
<id name="issueUserKey" column="issue_user_key" type="string" unsaved-value="undefined">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
```

Usually that is not the best way though.  You do in fact have a `<version/>` mapping which is usually a better fallback from the identifier for deciding between save/update without the overhead of querying the database.  You tried setting it to `unsaved-value="null"`.  But you did not show the property mapping for your IssueParticipant.dateAdded property (which is what you try to map as `<version/>`; you do realize version is incremented every update right?; also, you do know about `<timestamp/>` instead of `<version/>` right?).  Anyway, that is where your problem is.  Could you show the definition of your IssueParticipant.dateAdded property?

Comment: Sure; I edited the code in the OP to add dateAdded. It's just a java.util.Date.  Regarding the user of <version>, I always thought of it as more for optimistic locking; but yeah, according to axtavt's link I guess it can play a role in state detection.